# How do I get an attribute with namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Element xsi:Attribute="Test"></Element>
</Root>
```

I'm trying to read the "xsi:Attribute" attribute; the code is like this:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlText));

    var node = doc.Root.Descendants().First();
    XNamespace myNamespace = "xsi";
    var attribute = node.Attributes(myNamespace + "Attribute").First();
```

It throws a "Sequence contains no elements" exception in the last line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the actual namespace, not `"xsi"`, which is just a local lookup within the XML file itself for the real namespace:

```
        XNamespace myNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
```

Comment: Or "var myNamespace = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi");", what looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I believe its more generic):

```
XNamespace myNamespace = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi");
```